# In p5.js, is it possible to load a gif in the setup or preload function, and then use that gif multiple times elsewhere?

Tags: image, gif, p5.js

I have a class (lets call it "Enemies"), I want them to attack me when close enough (It will display an animated gif, that looks like a bite).

I've gotten all of this to work, except the only way I could figure it out, was by putting loadImage("attack.gif"), in the class. That got laggy really quick, since every time an enemy would spawn, it would have to reload that gif.

I've tried to use a loaded gif from the setup(), in my class, but all of their attacks were in sync.

Is there another way to do this?

Comment: it's hard to guess without seeing the actual code, however you should be able to load multiple gifs in `preload()` and store them in an array then modify the constructor of your `Enemies` class to take `p5.Image` as an argument instead of a string path to the image to load. When constructing instances, loop through the loaded images array and pass the `p5.Image` instances to the enemy instances as required. You should not need to keep reloading images in draw().

Comment: I'm not reloading constantly in draw(), It's only right when an Enemy spawns.
So what you're saying is if I loop through the loaded gifs, with `p5.Image`, and then have multiple sprites on the screen, they wont have in sync gifs?

Comment: I've looked at p5.Image, and it seems you might be right, but I'm having a little trouble applying it. If you can, show me a p5.editor with what you mean. All I need, is a gif (doesn't matter what it is), and when I click, it spawns another gif at my mouse location, that's not in sync, with the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can preload the gif (or gifs) and store them in a array which you can reuse later to draw in multiple places (e.g. multiple spawned enemies in your case).

Here's a basic example that demonstrates:

- loading images into an array
- spawning objects on screen (re)using the loaded images

```js
let images;
let enemies = [];

function preload(){
  // load images and store them in an array
  images = [
 loadImage("data:image/png;base64,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"),  loadImage("data:image/png;base64,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"),
     ];
}

function setup(){
  createCanvas(600, 600);
  imageMode(CENTER);
}

function draw(){
  background(255);
  // update + draw enemies
  for(let i = 0; i < enemies.length; i++){
    enemies[i].update();
  }
  text("click to spawn", 10, 15);
}

function mousePressed(){
  // pick a random image
  let randomImage = images[int(random(images.length))];
  // make a new enemy
  enemies.push(new Enemy(randomImage, mouseX, mouseY));
}

class Enemy {
  constructor(skin, x, y) {
    this.skin = skin;
    this.position = createVector(x, y);
    this.velocity = createVector(random(-1,1), random(-1,1));
  }
  update(){
    // add velocity
    this.position.add(this.velocity);
    // check borders and flip direction (roughly)
    if(this.position.x < 0 || this.position.x > width ||
       this.position.y < 0 || this.position.y > height){
       this.velocity.mult(-1);
    }
    // render
    push();
    blendMode(MULTIPLY);
    image(this.skin, this.position.x, this.position.y);
    pop();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.3.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

In the example above I'm using base64 encoded images to avoid CORS issues, however you should be fine loading your custom images instead.
The idea is to store the images globally so you can re-use them later when instantiating new enemies. (If you have a couple of images individual variables per image should do, otherwise an array will make it easier to manage)

Notice in `Enemy` constructor simply receives a reference to the previously loaded image:

```
// when declared
constructor(skin, x, y) {
    this.skin = skin;
// when intantiated
new Enemy(randomImage, mouseX, mouseY)
```

The only thing left to do is to render the image as needed:

```
image(this.skin, this.position.x, this.position.y);
```

**Update** Based on the comment and shared code the is that each enemy shares the same gif which updates at the same rate with the same frame number in sync.

One option would be to fill the `images` array with multiple copies of the same image, essentially reloading the gif once per enemy, though that seems wasteful.

Unfortunately `p5.Image.get()` returns a snapshot of the current frame and there is no magic function to clone a loaded gif, however the undocummented `gifProperties` holds the necessary data to manually do so:

```js
let images;
let enemies = [];

function preload(){
  // load images and store them in an array
  images = [
    loadImage("data:image/gif;base64,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"),
  ];
}

function setup(){
  createCanvas(600, 600);
  imageMode(CENTER);
}

function draw(){
  background(255);
  // update + draw enemies
  for(let i = 0; i < enemies.length; i++){
    enemies[i].update();
  }
  text("click to spawn", 10, 15);
}

function mousePressed(){
  // pick a random image
  let randomImage = images[int(random(images.length))];
  // offset the start frame of each enemy by one
  let startFrame = enemies.length % randomImage.numFrames();
  // make a new enemy
  enemies.push(new Enemy(cloneGif(randomImage,startFrame), mouseX, mouseY));
}

function cloneGif(gif, startFrame){
  let gifClone = gif.get();
  // access original gif properties
  gp = gif.gifProperties;
  // make a new object for the clone
  gifClone.gifProperties = {
    displayIndex: gp.displayIndex,
    // we still point to the original array of frames
    frames: gp.frames,
    lastChangeTime: gp.lastChangeTime,
    loopCount: gp.loopCount,
    loopLimit: gp.loopLimit,
    numFrames: gp.numFrames,
    playing: gp.playing,
    timeDisplayed: gp.timeDisplayed
  };
  // optional tweak the start frame
  gifClone.setFrame(startFrame);
  
  return gifClone;
}

class Enemy {
  constructor(skin, x, y) {
    this.skin = skin;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
  update(){
    image(this.skin, this.x, this.y);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.3.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

The `cloneGif` makes a new object (which means new start frame, etc.), however it should point to the original gif's `frames` (which hold the pixels / `ImageData`)

Now each enemy starts at a new frame.

I noticed that changing the delay seems to affect all enemies: once a delay is set to one it seems the underlying imagedata is copied at the same rate.

If you need to have different delay times you can manage still access the same gif frame `ImageData`, but rather than relying on `p5.Image` to control the gif playback (e.g. `setFrame()` / `delay()`) you'd need manually manage that and render to p5's canvas:

```js
let images;
let enemies = [];

function preload(){
  // load images and store them in an array
  images = [
    loadImage("data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODdhYABgAHcAACH/C05FVFNDQVBFMi4wAwEAAAAh+QQJCgAAACwAAAAAYABgAIIAAAAAAACsMjIfHx9NTU0AAAAAAAAAAAAD/wi63P4wykmrvTjrzbv/YCiOZGmeaKqubOu+cCzPdG3feK7vfO//wKBwSCwaj8ikcslsOp/QqHQ6DVivVMsVm6Vsrd2IYPwNjAXhxrl8TjPW33ay7C1/61scfWK/8/02exJ9eX+FOQOJXIOAEVeJAz6Qi46NEI+JkopghpSXVpBBk5wMhJ4AmJFDowEOpqQLqUSsrq+1AaFGrK+muUi7vH2+R8DBZcNMxodVyrBSzc5I0NOtQ9TQRNfNPseZDbwE4afFel/IqK/hBOObyzTdqqXp4tHkRuD01VT469FQ/KeaAOzzb14/OwVNqSMkEJQ3dKYW0JrjMB4vie2UyFJwUTzBxCIbPXwMErLDSCAlOZzMAc+EvUDmHo54WaNlCZpucurcybOnz59AgwodSrSo0aNIkypdyrSp06dPEwAAIfkECQoAAAAsGAADADAASACCAAAAAAAArDIyHx8fTU1NAAAAAAAAAAAAA/8Iutz+MMpJq7046827/2AojmRpnmiqrmzrvnAsz3Rt33iu73xvBsCgLCiMEYGdYkXAPAaYgovzAnVCpUdq83i1BAdgZcQ5nXzBaDGEnDUD0Wmkmy2XnAeLeGBMrzvuDnp8fYNogWF+DX2JDIAQggqLZAuOEpAAkmWYb2AUl5ltmwGGFnqgZKQYpqdHqRerrJVJsT+0JbF7XnW4uJShvLaiSsCsvrmirpGLBMxqAJfGycJszATO0MqjnYrLzYzYFZLVziDi3scj5taMs33jbOXd65Mf6nTtqZJ5iOi62njZ7ikAR6GSvoH8BkXb9kDToQHDfnEC2DDUw4hEFlL8Y7EPwaddE02AkyViZMgSlxIAACH5BAkKAAAALBgAAAAwAEsAggAAAIqKir29vQAAAKwyMh8fH01NTQAAAAP/CLrc/jDKSau9OOvAtYdc8I1MSH6hoJ5eurKZK8BWaHPqTEe3ne+8Hu4FdMiKlSNyolwuTA2oUyF9dqbUa0mLBXEVv24VTJyOAeGues0uDt7w9gIelwPo7zZhjx/sCWp/fX+BfHiEXX19aop4jI11a4t2k3KVbZdsmZKOH5ARkJEOoY2gpKaknQ+pqJsFr5GplXCvBRS1sbJ0c2+1t7B5Crq7wr2vF7jDjb4Zycp9zBjOz3TRI6kG2aI02NrBQN0G2xjUcNnipxPlb+es6uvt6avGtg2Q8cQMzqP0/Ir44/bZ6zfwn7d8CwTe+dZKF4VN/oY9VNVQ1sQBF9dhPKFxN5yGjgwz0DrWDNhGcgSlmfyYEtlKCyPrkVCIytoHmhBissDJQGcRnj6BAG1JQ6HHRBQ1JeU0IAEAIfkECQoAAAAsGAAAADAASACCAAAAvb29ioqKAAAArDIyHx8fTU1NAAAAA/8IutzuIb5Jq43B6k0x/6AHjpdEno+IjkLruiv5zjE7w/WHA66aU7ue6QdsLYQZ4s6BJDKWjaZTAX22fNNKtZrlGaPfrlXADIvP6LR6zW673/B4bkCvx+t2OJ7uJvj3A34Ea4KAgoR/e4dqgIBrjXuPkHlsjnqRl3grkxSTlA6ekJ2ho6GYD6allgwFrZSmq3WtBRqzr7CaCrKtta58uri3A7MftsGQxCPGx4DJIMvMeM6boQbWn0Sm1gbYP9rXvyfRddupFuN05aTn6OqepdPAje7dy6B08QCT9OEL9g27aAGExG+Ag3/6+k2IpmGVKlwNTz2EFdEgO3QKxWHMSGI2I0cOAReYA4DwQ0h5nBSUBImPF0pRKn1Z3HAyxkpULQXalFkxH4mbzVxOgYZMqBOijXzWQJoAACH5BAkKAAAALBgAAwAwAEUAggAAAIqKir29vQAAAKwyMh8fH01NTQAAAAP/CLrc7iG+SauNwepNMf+bIIKkJgplOp1q+2Csm8KjXNKozXn6LPW3H3BILBqPyKRyyWw6n9CodEqtFgfYbDSrhXKxToL4OxATlmayGT3+rpVk8jL+ndO7oLtGbrnr+3WAfnwVhBR/DAWKeAuDAw5ZigUakowKjpBYkpSLYA2Yn5qKH5WOg5skpaZ3qCCqq3GtLbCWOrSeQ7ePKrpZBr+ghb0DvwbBh8PFx5dfssx+yrgLr3TOAI7Ru4mdftbYwNIK1Np7dNm1Nnfn4bbm4FxAw/Ay8ugk9ewfkaPPiKol+yb1ozONG0BRAq8NKljA3oOANv4JslZCorABFFMZDMUlDqOLcWQ8tgDZjN+QcQkAACH5BAkKAAAALBgABgAwAEIAggAAAIqKir29vQAAAKwyMh8fH01NTQAAAAP/CLrcviG+SauNwepNMf+gI4xhWY2CqYrk6r5wLM90bd94ru987//AoHBILBppg6RSqFwGm8kfYQodTAm8a/WapUK5oaqmKraQoeOzs6JeU9pRM1pRqLsnZXayXnDw7w95b3t1fnZxek1pA3wUf4gLcAMOSo0Wj5MNkpSEfZeHmQybmp0fmJJqliCnqGSqpqCtroUvsoAwtpAyuaElvLyLv63BwqOiUK8KkgbMgKyznsdtzAbOsWfJAMvNugDPH9vV3bhw1Le15dy96NPqgirhauTt4mQrlbTacAuYvqXK++iA8scon7F+HPBFW4EwUbYSDQcVXKgiIsAmD188q5LRCMVGZPlmPEsAADs="),
  ];
}

function setup(){
  createCanvas(600, 600);
  imageMode(CENTER);
}

function draw(){
  background(255);
  // update + draw enemies
  for(let i = 0; i < enemies.length; i++){
    enemies[i].update();
  }
  text("click to spawn", 10, 15);
}

function mousePressed(){
  // pick a random image
  let randomImage = images[int(random(images.length))];
  // make a new enemy
  let enemy = new Enemy({frames: randomImage.gifProperties.frames, gifWidth: randomImage.width, gifH: randomImage.height}, mouseX, mouseY);
  // pick a random start frame
  enemy.currentFrame = int(random(images.length));
  // pick a random per gif frame delay (e.g. the larger the number the slower the gif will play)
  enemy.frameDelay = int(random(40, 240));
  enemies.push(enemy);
}

class Enemy {
  constructor(gifData, x, y) {
    this.frames = gifData.frames;
    this.offX = -int(gifData.gifWidth * 0.5);
    this.offY = -int(gifData.gifHeight * 0.5);
    this.currentFrame = 0;
    this.numFrames = this.frames.length;
    this.frameDelay = 100;
    this.lastFrameUpdate = millis();
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
  
  update(){
    let millisNow = millis();
    // increment frame
    if(millisNow - this.lastFrameUpdate >= this.frameDelay){
      this.currentFrame = (this.currentFrame + 1) % this.numFrames;  
      this.lastFrameUpdate = millisNow;
    }
     // render directly to p5's canvas context
 drawingContext.putImageData(this.frames[this.currentFrame].image, this.x + this.offX, this.y + this.offY);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.3.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Also notice the p5.Image does something nice about transparency (even when the original gif is missing it): that's something you'd need to manually address if going this lower level route.

Comment: I tried this, I used your code exactly, but replaced the images with my gifs, but all the gifs were in sync, I'm trying to have them all be unique.

Comment: I can't post my attempt, since the gif is local, plus it's the exact same code as yours. What I mean by in sync, is that 2 gifs, with 10 frames each, standing right next to each other, will be played at the same time, and when I try to make another one, it will start it's frame at the same frame as the other 2, instead of at 0.

Comment: how about sharing on https://editor.p5js.org/ ? you can upload gifs there. how are you playing back the gifs ? (in theory it should be possible to pick separate start frames and/or playback rates)

Comment: Here you go [Spider_gif](https://editor.p5js.org/tbackens/sketches/2Rq7cWgIH)

Comment: @ThomasBackens check out the updated answer above.
If the answer above was useful vote up and if it was the solution to your question mark it with the green check mark :)
I've checked out your Game on github: pretty cool! Best of luck with the development. Also check out sprite sheets / texture atlases (and tools that can help generate those (such as [SpriteSheetPacker](https://www.codeandweb.com/free-sprite-sheet-packer)

Comment: Happy to hear that and thank you for the vote and check mark. If you need to do lower level gif manipulation with p5.js remember it's open source, so you can always peak how they [decode/blit the gif](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/blob/main/src/image/loading_displaying.js#L156) and how the [gif frames are managed in time](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/blob/main/src/image/p5.Image.js)(e.g. search for gif in the source file). Best of luck!